# Is the meaning of "access to books" literal in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cannot figure out if the meaning of "books" is literal in the following movie line.

Here's the context:

> An old sport veteran is making a deal with a head administrator. He says he wants half the gate, merchandise, pay-per-view and "access to the books".

What does books refer to? Could it be the reservations? Because he mentioned "the gate" before. All he wants is money. What benefit does accessing the books have for him?

Comment: Probably the accounting books, so he'll know what the total gate (tickets fees collected) and other amounts are. This is to ensure he's getting the full amount due in the deal.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/book?locale=en) has: **2.1 books** A set of records or accounts.

Comment: Half the gate: Half the money paid at the entrance, half the money earned by merchandise and pay-per-view and access to look at the accounting to see he is not being cheated